# -doclet is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: command-line, doclet

I'm trying to do some tutorials for XHTML Doclet which use the command line but it does not recognize the command '-doclet' I'm not very familiar with the command line to begin with so I am not sure how to precede from here. Is there a file I need to download for -doclet to work correctly?

Comment: Is not `-doclet` an additional argument to the `javadoc` command?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The tutorial I was trying was wack and was having me use it improperly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the system did recognize the command, but that the example I was following had me enter the commands out of order. Everything is working fine now.